# Name that Sandwich: I am the End

Tags: riddle

This is no enigma
Just a shameful stigma
We have split apart for good
A malevolent stance taken as it should

Our contract now null and void
Desiring to inhabit a separate planetoid
Once classed as my property
Now free of the depravity

For what we may have created
now in despair, not appreciated
for we'll pay for our sacrilege
Once we dine with our heritage

So now we divide our surrounding
separate haemorrhoids not corresponding
Take our past in unrelated directions
no longer our paths have intersections

For we are at the end of the road
although different, still a toad
This heartfelt decision
Has caused this incision

Comment: @AE Lovely thought process, I do mean haemorrhoids, but at the same time you have to ask your self is their deeper meaning to haemorrhoids. Or is there a meaning thats shallow.

Comment: Why "sandwich"?

Comment: @FlorianF You could say it is shameless advertising, as they all share a common name. You could on the other hand assume its just my calling card, my cathphrase if you will. Either way I doubt is has any bearing or relevance to the riddle rather than to let you know its my riddle.

Comment: @FlorianF No worries, As normal and friendly your question was. There are some others who will criticise what I say no matter what, so I thought I'd beat them to it :D

Comment: @Oblongamous I think I got it. When is it ready to be answered (if)?

Comment: I have an answer, but I'm not great with figurative language and can't interpret the entire passage.

Comment: @DragonLord fair enough what do you think it is and where are you falling down?

Comment: @Oblongamous - Speaking of sandwiches, have you seen [this](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/18976999#18976999)? :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Note:** My interpretation of the passage is incomplete as I'm not all too familiar with the topic. Any pointers would be appreciated.

---

### Answer

> **Divorce**, the end of marriage

---

*This is no enigma

Just a shameful stigma

We have split apart for good

A malevolent stance taken as it should*

> The former spouses have separated. It's pretty shameful, and it's typically the result of hatred towards each other.

*Our contract now null and void*

> Marriage is a legally-binding contract in many jurisdictions; divorce terminates that contract.

*Desiring to inhabit a separate planetoid*

> The former spouses live separately.

*For what we may have created

now in despair, not appreciated*

> Children are inevitably upset as a result of a divorce.

*for we'll pay for our sacrilege*

> In many religions, marriage is considered sacred, and divorce sacrilegious.

*Once we dine with our heritage*

> Inheritance problems can come up as a result of divorce. It is impossible to stay out of hell, your heritage = what has been passed down to you = DNA. Your past relations in hell.

*Take our past in unrelated directions

no longer our paths have intersections*

> The former spouses separate and never want to meet up again.

*This heartfelt decision

Has caused this incision*

> In many legal systems, divorce is a decision made by a judge in court.

although different, still a toad

> the reference to the frog turning into a prince happily ever after in marriage. This now divorced, your still a frog

So now we divide our surrounding
separate haemorrhoids not corresponding

> haemorrhoids = piles, the metaphoric description of dividing the assets of the marriage and splitting them, which are never correspond. Ones pile is always worth more.

Once classed as my property
Now free of the depravity

> It was once common knowledge that the wife was property of the man (still is in some communities).  Now free of being an object through divorce.